# When would/will I need a dedicated database server?

Tags: mysql

I currently have a single dedicated server handling my web server and dedicated server for a small number of websites, however, I am running two sites that deal with fairly large databases (Large to me at least).

My server has 3 gigs of ram and is running Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. I occasionally get warnings from Plesk about my MySQL status being in the Red.

I really have no idea what is a high load or when I'll need a dedicated server for my databases. Looking at phpMyAdmin, I have the following stats:

Query statistics: Since its startup, 10,145,576 queries have been sent to the server (Server has been up 16 days)

7.15 queries per second, 430 per minute (I think)

Select query types have run 7,178 k.

Open_tables is 64
Opened_tables is 257.2 k

I'm just wondering at what point this will require another server, and how I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a generously sized server running a fairly light load. I have no idea what Plesk means by the MySQL status being in the red but if you are having any issues at all I'm confident you merely need to fine tune the MySQL parameters. The "out of the box" settings for most things like MySQL and Apache really aren't suitable for most hosted servers.

I don't know how you'd do that if the only access you have is through a control panel but what I did was to use one of the tuneup scripts (available from a number of sites) to set the parameters of my server, which has only a fraction of the resources yours has and a similar level of activity. While I had major problems with the initial install, which was done by the hosting company, I've had no issues since changing the parameters.

Comment: Oh I have SSH access. I used to run my server completely from SSH, but recently had to re-install so I got Plesk added on. It makes the mundane a lot easier. I've tweaked the Apache settings to fix them up, but not MySQL, so I'll go look into that. Good to know that this is considered a light load.